# How to make function for saving post

Tags: javascript, function, post, save

```html
  <div id="textareaWrap">
    <textarea  id="wall"></textarea>
    <div id="sharebtn">
      <a class="button Share" style="" id="shareButton"> Post</a>
    </div>
```

When I write something in the `textarea` and post it, the posting is succesful, but when I refresh the page the post is deleted. If someone can make a function to get posts to stay posted after refresh (like Facebook), I would appreciate it.

Comment: facebook give alert message .

Comment: yap,but it's not facebook i made page with this when I wrote some information its posted but when I refresh the page post is deleted.I need something like this:

Comment: function downloadInnerHtml(filename, elId, mimeType) {
    var elHtml = document.getElementById(elId).innerHTML;
    var link = document.createElement('txt');
    mimeType = mimeType || 'text/plain';

    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    link.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + mimeType  +  ';charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(elHtml));
    link.click();

Comment: When you refresh a Facebook page it asks the Facebook server what it should show. You need to do the same thing with your server.

Comment: U don't understand me.Let me make example:This is textarea/_____/ /Post/ this is post button when i do this /Testing/ then click /Post/ it's call me ajax for wall posting and i get under the textarea Admin under that Testing and I can see that but when I refresh the page that Is deleted.I whanna Function like when I wrote that that is wrote in html like <p>Admin</p> then the text i get in like in form <h3>here text i wrote in txtarea</h3>